# How do you handle a multi-color header in Bootstrap cards?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am using Bootstrap Cards, and I have made a header which uses linear-gradient styling for the background. The idea is that one piece of information goes into the red section of the header, in this case Reserved/Not Reserved, and then another piece of information is meant to go into the green part of the header.

The problem, as you can see in the picture, is that the text from the green area will flow over into the the red part.

[image]

Of course this happens because I am styling the entire header element, so of course it won't care where the content in that header is located.

So then I tried to create a row inside the header, give that row two columns and then add a different color to these, but then this happens:

[image]

The elements basically ignore the card completely.

I would like to have a header that looks like the one in the first picture, but I want it to be two separate elements for each color, so that text from one color won't overlap into the next.

Any suggestions? It should be fairly easy right? I just can't figure it out.

The current code (with the elements separated):

```
    <b-col class="my-3">
      <div class="card">
        <b-row class="card-header">
          <b-col class="card-header-one" style="background-color: #f34860">
            <h4 v-if="table.reserved" class="ml-4" style="color: white; margin-top: 5px;">{{$t('Reserved')}}</h4>
            <h4 v-if="!table.reserved" class="ml-4" style="color: white; margin-top: 5px;">{{$t('Not reserved')}}</h4>
          </b-col>
          <b-col class="card-header-two" style="background-color: #28a745">
            <h4 style="color: white; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 40px;">{{ 'some text' }}</h4>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>
     <div class="card-body">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </b-col>
```

Comment: This is an HTML and CSS question. I suggest you reformulate to show us rendered HTML and include Bootstrap CSS (via CDN) so we can see and work the problem. Vue code is not workable. Put it in a snippet demo using the editor.